# Dynamic related select menus in Alpinejs for product attributes

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, alpine.js

I'm working on a commerce project which needs dynamic selects depending on each other for product attributes:
for example consider Size, Weight and Color:

```
<div class="bg-white" x-data="{
    attributes:[
      {'name':'size','label':'Size','desc':'Size field description'},
      {'name':'weight','label':'Weight','desc':'Weight field description'},
      {'name':'color','label':'Color','desc':'Color field description'}
      ],
    products:[
      {'id':1, 'size':'small', 'weight':'1 kg', 'color': 'red', 'price': 100},
      {'id':2, 'size':'small', 'weight':'1 kg', 'color': 'blue', 'price': 200},
      {'id':3, 'size':'small', 'weight':'2 kg', 'color': 'green', 'price': 300},
      {'id':4, 'size':'small', 'weight':'2 kg', 'color': 'yellow', 'price': 400},
      {'id':5, 'size':'large', 'weight':'4 kg', 'color': 'pink', 'price': 500},
      {'id':6, 'size':'large', 'weight':'4 kg', 'color': 'navy blue', 'price': 600},
      {'id':7, 'size':'large', 'weight':'4 kg', 'color': 'cyan', 'price': 700},
      {'id':8, 'size':'large', 'weight':'6 kg', 'color': 'amber', 'price': 800},
      {'id':9, 'size':'large', 'weight':'6 kg', 'color': 'black', 'price': 900}
    ],
    selected: [
    ]
}" >
        <ul>
          <template x-for="(attribute, index) in attributes">
            <div>
              <label for="attribute.name" x-text="attribute.label"></label>
              <select name="attribute.name" id="attribute.name"  @change="selected[attribute.name] = $el.value; console.log(selected);">
                <template x-for="product in products.filter((p) => Object.keys(selected).every((k) => selected[k] === p[k]))">
                  <option :value="product[attribute.name]" x-text="product[attribute.name]"></option>
                </template>
              </select>
            </div>
          </template>
        </ul>


    </div>
```

I want to have three select menus for each attribute which contains correct options:
for example in the data below you select size between 'small' or 'large' then values in the second select will change according to that and then color the same way and finally show the correct selected price.

Could you please help me a little I cant figure it out
Currently it makes no filtering and only shows all value of all products and reportingly

[now its not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrZiK.png)

I'm doing this Laravel and Alpinejs so I can create extra functions, data sets and during server side rendering...

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `selected` variable should be an object, not an array. So change it to `selected: {}` in `x-data` then the filtering will work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right it will work! But could you please tell me how can I prevent items from repeating?

Comment: I suggest to create an unique attribute list, e.g. for size: `['small', 'large']` and loop over these lists. Now for some reason you are looping over the list of products at the filtering form. So when multiple products have the same size, then the size dropdown will have repeated values.